# Where can a civilian obtain centrifuge training/testing?

Tags: flight-training, usa, g-forces

Where can a civilian get high g-force training/testing in a centrifuge?  (Likely by paying.)  Preferably with and without a g-suit.  Preferably based in the US, maybe Canada.

I'm betting the US Air Force centrifuge in San Antonio, Texas, and Canada's military centrifuge in Toronto would laugh and/or hang up the phone if asked.

Crossing my fingers there's a private or educational facility that would be an option.

Comment: I sit in my chair and spin around. Sometimes I hold one of the cats while spinning, then put him down afterwards and watch him stagger diagonally across the room.

Comment: I don't have a cat.  I have a pug.  I tried this and he puked all over.  I blame you.  :-)

Comment: I am really curious to know why.  Would you share your motivations?

Comment: @TylerDurden Have you tried taping buttered toast to your cat's back & dropping him off the roof? :)

Comment: The ride at Epcot

Comment: @Simon, I'd give a kidney, and a something I probably can't mention under terms, to go back and attempt becoming a fighter pilot, if my wife could have been happy with it. (Not sure she could go through what so many brave families go through.) I'd give a kidney, but not the other part, for a flight in the back of Blue Angel #7 during a show. I'm 34 so can't start fighter pilot training. And no shot with the Angels - not a celebrity or in the media. When younger, someone told me needing contacts/glasses/surgery disqualified me. I'm happy believing they were right at the time, changing later.

Comment: Civilians can pilot/own something like an L-39C Albatros. (I doubt a F-4/F-104/F-100F/MiG-15/T-33 will be in reach for non-millionaires to own.)  Private pilot with single-engine landing/instrument rating, 1000 hours with 500 hours PIC, endorsements for high-performance/complex aircraft and high-altitude training. Then you start training on L-39C. Just beginning flight lessons. Many, many years off, but committed. I like cautiously over-doing things. Thinking centrifuge would be worth it, before someday giving it a shot with an instructor ready to take controls.  Would like to know my limit.

Comment: @andrewmh20, only gives 2.5g.  :-(  Maybe I could crank up the power...

Comment: I believe I might be able to recommend you a facility in The Netherlands. If you are interested, I'll ssl

Comment: You might be interested in www.aircombat.com.  It's probably cheaper than any centrifuge you'd find, a whole lot more fun, and still capable of giving you that dose of vitamin G.

Comment: This should be an answer, but I don't have enough points: You can get a pretty comprehensive experience at https://www.rocketcenter.com/simulator/gforceaccelerator - they operate a flight simulator, g-force accelerator, and gyroscopes

Comment: @MrMartin Interesting.  Their website says up to 3g though.  I wonder if they'd ever agree to go beyond that, but maybe theirs can't even go that high.

Answer (score 5):

This is a tough one. I don't know of any civilian facilities (but it does not mean they don't exist). This is a bit of a shot in the dark but in my opinion you may want to contact NASA about the [Ames Research Center 20-G centrifuge](http://www.nasa.gov/ames/research/space-biosciences/20-g-centrifuge). If for no other reason than this is the only non military one that seems to exist. For what its worth high speed centrifuges are not that simple despite just being something that spins in a circle. The speeds that the unit spin at are extremely high to say the least, to do this with out ripping the whole thing apart requires careful balancing and construction so they are not exactly something you can build at home. Here is at least [one company](http://www.amst.co.at/en/training-simulation-products/human-training-centrifuge/) that is building them and installing them elsewhere in the world. They list a bunch of installs for other militaries that might be more open to a civilian coming in but who knows.

Comment: NASA also has a centrifuge at Goddard capable of accelerating 2.5 tons at 30 G, but iirc it is for satellites, not people.